# How to fix "Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support" in Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

When I open my app in Heroku, it gives me this error:

```
2022-04-10T19:49:02.067488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=likeblogs.herokuapp.com request_id=765d2963-1ae8-47f4-958f-672ee4a7d99a fwd="189.102.131.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-10T19:49:02.751766+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=likeblogs.herokuapp.com request_id=00210037-68e7-4cd7-aa1c-c5cb9c1e8143 fwd="189.102.131.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have already declared the requirements.txt and set gunicorn and in my Procfile like this :

```
web: gunicorn main.py:app
```

I have these errors:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What else do your logs say, above the "App crashed" lines?

Comment: i refresh the question have  the image there now

Comment: Why would you switch from nice, text-based content to an image? [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Either way, that's just the last few lines of the error output. Please show us _all of it_.

Comment: The clipped error message says "*Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support*". Have you tried that? See related: [WTForms: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61356834/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

The `.py` shouldn't be included: the format is [$(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME)](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html).

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What do the logs say now? And does it work locally when you run `gunicorn main:app`?

Comment: Yes it work  when i run it in my machine work normaly but when i try to deply in the Heroku it don't work

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with file paths. What do the logs tell you?

Comment: this is the log only says the erros in the questions

Comment: i put a image on the question

Comment: Have you included `email_validator` in requirements.txt?

Comment: I'll see in a minute

Comment: no i din't include

Comment: You'll need to include it. The error message says you simply need to install it, and you can do so by adding it to requirements.txt.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH you are I N C R E D I  B L E